# How to send FCM notification to app from web

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

I am developing chat app which is based on Firebase Database and Storage. Everything is working fine, but now I need implementation of FCM to receive notification on app when app is in background or foreground. I can't find a way to implement in PHP which listen any changes in firebase database and if there is any change then send push notification to app.

There is so many code which send notification from PHP, but none is based on Firebase database and even official documentation has Node.js guide which my shared hosting doesn't support.

I already implemented FCM code on my app side which is tested from Firebase Console.

Here is my Firebase database structure 
[image: Firebase Database Structure]

Comment: use a postman. :)

Comment: You should have a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Specifically at [Realtime Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

Comment: @AL.my server don't support Npm

Comment: A detail blog : http://sforsuresh.in/sending-push-notifications-to-android-mobile-using-firebase-php

Comment: May be this link very helpful: [send push notifications using firebase cloud messaging.](https://devnote.in/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-with-php/)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Sending a push notification is only a matter of sending a post request to FCM servers.

Here is working example:

```
$data = json_encode($json_data);
//FCM API end-point
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
//api_key in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
$server_key = 'YOUR_KEY';
//header with content_type api key
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key='.$server_key
);
//CURL request to route notification to FCM connection server (provided by Google)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Example of the JSON pay load:

```
[
    "to" => 'DEVICE_TOKEN',
    "notification" => [
        "body" => "SOMETHING",
        "title" => "SOMETHING",
        "icon" => "ic_launcher"
    ],
    "data" => [
        "ANYTHING EXTRA HERE"
    ]
]
```

Comment: fetch data from your database, and build that playload message thats all

Comment: @meda I had a question... In this case what will be the server key if I want to send a notification to ios device? Or how to use pem file to send a notification to ios device?

Comment: Shows "Error=MissingRegistration".

Comment: Hello, I've followed so many examples like yours but I don't receive any notification, neither the notification get listed in firebase console, even if the CURL response is positive..
status: 200
string(143) "{"multicast_id":8573812091209374332,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1550852694105682%0762e9f8f9fd7ecd"}]}"

when I send it via firebase console to the same device token it works , any idea?

device token got from firebase cloud firestore

Comment: @VishnuTasok I was getting this error, too. turn out it is the header not setting properly, if you use POSTMAN, u must choose raw in the body and select JSON(application/json) from the dropdown menu next to the raw radio button. IT WILL THEN OVERWRITE YOUR HEADER. So even you entered the header in the header tab, a wrong setting in body tab will get your header overwritten in POSTMAN.

Comment: @meda I am troubleshooting an issue I face in one of my apps and wanted to know that the above-mentioned approach falls in which category from this list https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#choosing-a-server-option

Comment: @meda meda how to send `channel_id` in http request? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh anything extra goes under the `data` key as indicated in my post `data => ['channel_id'=>123]`

Comment: How can I send the message to all devices? Thanks

Answer (score 32):

Try this code it works for me android as well as iOS

```
<?php
    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $token = "your device token";
    $serverKey = 'your server token of FCM project';
    $title = "Notification title";
    $body = "Hello I am from Your php server";
    $notification = array('title' =>$title , 'body' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
    $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
    $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    //Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //Close request
    if ($response === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: How to add multiple device id or registration id in to

Comment: Make an array of your device token $token = ["device_token_1", "device_token_2"]
or $token = array("device_token_1", "device_token_2")

Comment: Thanks for the reply , and we need to change the parameter to "registration_ids" else , it will show error

Comment: I think no problem with variable name but "registration_ids" is standard for FCM. thanks @ShawkatAlam

Comment: @RiajulIslam iam getting invalid registration id error

Comment: @NishantSaini Invalid Registration ID Check the formatting of the registration ID that you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration ID the phone receives in the com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT intent and that you're not truncating it or adding additional characters. Happens when error code is InvalidRegistration.

Comment: very nice  digipaz

Comment: it returns message id but nothing happens in registered devices into a topic, I'm sure that the device registration is right because it works when I send a notification manually from firebase console

Comment: how do i send my deeplink to open my custom intent in android

Comment: `'sound' => 'default'` not worked for me. I did not hear any sound when received notification. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can send the post request without curl (which was not available on my server)

```
sendNotification("New post!", "How to send a simple FCM notification in php", ["new_post_id" => "605"], "YOUR_SERVER_KEY");

function sendNotification($title = "", $body = "", $customData = [], $serverKey = ""){
    if($serverKey != ""){
        ini_set("allow_url_fopen", "On");
        $data = 
        [
            "to" => '/topics/new_post',
            "notification" => [
                "body" => $body,
                "title" => $title,
            ],
            "data" => $customData
        ];

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode( $data ),
                'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                            "Accept: application/json\r\n" . 
                            "Authorization:key=".$serverKey
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
        $result = file_get_contents( "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", false, $context );
        return json_decode( $result );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Postman instead.
Open Postman extension in chrome and use the POST url https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send.

[image]

[image]

Comment: App side notification working fine i checked through FCM console

Answer (score 2):

```
function MultiandroidNotification($deviceToken, $message,$type,$title=null,$sub_title=null,$device_type=null,$data = null,$content_available = null)
{

    if($content_available == 1){
        $content_available = false;
    }else{
        $content_available =  true;
    }
    if($type == 12 || $type == 13){
        $priority = '';
    }else{
        $priority = 'high';
    }

    $deviceToken = array_values($deviceToken);
    $no = null;

    $apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $notification = array("text" => "test",'badge' => "1",'sound' => 'shutter.wav','body'=>$message,'icon'=>'notif_icn','title'=>$title,'priority'=>'high','tag'=>'test','vibrate'=> 1,'alert'=> $message);

    $msg = array('message'=> $message,'title'=> $title,'sub_title'=> $sub_title,'type'=>$type,'activitydata' => $data);

    if($device_type == 'android'){
        $fields = array("content_available" => true,"priority" => "high",'registration_ids'=> $deviceToken,'data'=> $msg);
    }else{
        $fields = array('notification' => $notification,"content_available" => $content_available,"priority" => $priority,'registration_ids'=> $deviceToken,'data'=> $msg);
    }

    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,'Content-Type: application/json');

    if ($headers){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
    }
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            return false; //probably you want to return false
        }
        if ($httpCode != 200) {
            return false; //probably you want to return false
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
}
```

Comment: Getting error : 
{"multicast_id":132596829075065854,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidParameters: The
data field in the request can not contain duplicate keys."}]}

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php  
 function sendFCM($title, $urduTitle, $pathimg, $tokens) {
  $url1 = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  $apiKey = "AAAA4zDorrw:APA91bHgehYGI5QWyvUv47FWizkjybMK36hdZQH4PHwdGBQcKCBpdCFUSqNSNGZWcO-l07YfIBuXv_lK9rMEr5y0Ms9CvrwCUmuSn8M0aqj3oGg10bpCyxvm0PYrrrvCF-R4zHqSYyqR";
  $headers = array (
    'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
  );
    // Add notification content to a variable for easy reference
  $notifData = [
    'title' => "".$urduTitle,
    'body' => "".$title,
     'priority' => "high",
    'image'=> "".$pathimg//,//Optional
   // 'click_action' => "activities.SinglePostActivity" //Action/Activity - Optional
  ];
  $dataPayload = [
   'to'=> $_SESSION['lastinsertedid'], 
   'title'=>"".$urduTitle, 
   'title1' =>"".$title,
   'channel'=>'Posts',
   'icon' =>"".$pathimg.""
  ];
 // echo $tokens;
  $apiBody = array(
    'notification' => $notifData,
    'data' => $dataPayload,
    'time_to_live' => 600,
    'to' => ''.$tokens
    //'to' => '/topics/all'
  );
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($apiBody));
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.