# Firebase RealtimeDatabase in chat app not retrieve messages by time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: a photo] 
When i retrieve messages for chat from Firebase , it was retrieve them without time message sent in it

i tried orderbychild(timestamp);
but it not worked for my case

```
    Intent intent;
    List<ChatModel> data;
    private RecyclerView mRecy;
    ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    String mId;
    Button sendmessage;
    private EditText mEditWriteMessage;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    ChatModel chatModel;
    ChatModel chatModel2;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mechanic_profile);
        sendmessage = findViewById(R.id.sendmessage);
        mEditWriteMessage = findViewById(R.id.editWriteMessage);
        intent = getIntent();
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);
        mRecy = findViewById(R.id.recy);

        mRecy.setHasFixedSize(true);


        mRecy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecy.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CHHAATS");

        DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CHHAATS");

        databaseReference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    chatModel2 = snapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);

    if (chatModel2.getFrom().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chatModel2.getTo().equals(intent.getStringExtra("receiver"))
            || chatModel2.getFrom().equals(intent.getStringExtra("receiver")) && chatModel2.getTo().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {


        data.add(chatModel2);

    }


            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mRecy.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            chatModel2 = snapshot.getValue(ChatModel.class);
        }
            if (chatModel2.getFrom().equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && chatModel2.getTo().equals(intent.getStringExtra("receiver"))
                    || chatModel2.getFrom().equals(intent.getStringExtra("receiver")) && chatModel2.getTo().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {


                data.add(chatModel2);



            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mRecy.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

        sendmessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v){
                String message = mEditWriteMessage.getText().toString();
                String receiver = intent.getStringExtra("receiver");
                String sender = firebaseUser.getUid();
                meth(message, receiver, sender);
            }
            });
        }

        void meth (String message, String receiver, String sender){

            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CHHAATS");
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            hashMap.put("text", message);
            hashMap.put("from", sender);
            hashMap.put("to", receiver);
            reference.child(receiver).push().setValue(hashMap);


        }


    }
```

the actual result is the messages retrieve without looking its time 
what i need is retrieve the message by its date and time  but firebase do another thing

Comment: How about manually storing the current time into database i.e when message is being sent to database with message send timestamp and do fetching on those sent timestamps

Comment: not tried it yet ,can you provide code or provide more information about it please

Comment: Yes sure i can! please wait i'm a busy person so will post the answer lately

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use FCM instead of the realtime database.

`onChildAdded` will get triggered on every single device when a user sends a message, this is a security issue and really bad for performance, imagine that you have 1k of messages being sent every second, this would make your app very very slow.

My advice is to save a firebase id of each user on the database and then use that id to send a notification to that specific user take a look at [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) to receive messages.

To send messages my advice would be autenticate the user on your server using the login token, from the server you can query Firebase to send the message. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989007/how-to-send-fcm-notification-to-app-from-web) you can also use Firebase Functions just keep your `api_key` in a safe place

Comment: i need to change my realtime database structure ?

Comment: yea i make this structure for use FCM

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think that all messages will be ordered by the latest, so I think the problem is in RecyclerView, and I think the solution in RecyclerView too.

after fetching all messages to your RecyclerView should be putting this line:

```
mRecy.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecy.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: mRecy.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1); same i added

Comment: but what i want is how  i could sort the nodes by their data and time

Comment: Defaultly each new child inserted should be placed automatically at the bottom in the database, then when you try to display the messages in RecyclerView will display them from top to bottom and when you used this line above will move the user to the latest message in this activity